# Converting MySQL TEXT field with breaklines to XML by Perl script returns a malformed notation

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I have a table in MySQL that has one field defined as TEXT. The information is fed to the database by a webform using a textarea.

I'm using the following script to generate an XML with the information of the table:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;
use XML::Generator::DBI;
use XML::Handler::YAWriter;

my $dbh = DBI->connect ("DBI:access info goes here",
                           { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0});
my $out = XML::Handler::YAWriter->new (AsFile => "-", Encoding=>"ISO-8859-1");
   my $gen = XML::Generator::DBI->new (
                                   Handler => $out,
                                   dbh => $dbh
                               );
   $gen->execute ("SELECT text FROM table");
   $dbh->disconnect ();
```

The problem is that when the text entered has breaklines it generates a malformed XML:

```
<text {http://axkit.org/NS/xml-generator-dbi}encoding="HASH(0x9c43ba0)">PHA+YWlqZHNvaWFqZG9pYXNqZG9pYXNqb2RpanNhaW9kanNhb2lkYXNvaWo8L3A+DQo8cD5zPC9w
Pg0KPHA+ZDwvcD4NCjxwPmFzPC9wPg0KPHA+ZHNhPC9wPg0KPHA+ZDwvcD4NCjxwPnNhZHNhZHNh
ZHM8L3A+DQo8cD4mbmJzcDs8L3A+DQo8cD5hc2Rhc2Rzc2FkZHNkc2FzZHNhPC9wPg0KPHA+Jm5i
c3A7PC9wPg0KPHA+YXNkZHNhZHNhYXNkc2Rhc2RhYXNkPC9wPg==
</text>
```

For example if the text entered is:

```
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
```

It outputs the malformed XML, but when the text is:

```
<p>One</p> <p>Two</p>
```

It prints out the XML correctly.

Is there any way to 'strip' the breakline from the textarea or ignore it in the creation of the XML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might work to enforce well-formed-ness:

```
$text = s|(?i)(<br)>|$1 />|gm;
```

Which will turn any bare linebreak tag into an empty tag compliant with XML well-formed-ness.

With my cursory look at the classes you're using, it looks like if you can step into the handler chain, and handle, say `characters`, you might be able to do something likes this before the call to `XML::Generator::DBI->execute`.

```
$gen->set_content_handler(
    SAXHandlerWrapper->new(
        characters => sub { 
            s|(?i)(<br)>|$1 />|gm; 
            return $out->characters( $_ ) 
        }
    )    
);
```

Where the following behavior defines SAXHandlerWrapper:

```
package SAXHandlerWrapper;
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp         qw<croak>;
use Params::Util qw<_CODE _HASH _IDENTIFIER _INSTANCE>;
use Scalar::Util qw<blessed>;

sub _make_handler {
    my $name = shift || $_;
    return if __PACKAGE__->can( $name );
    no strict;
    *$name = sub {
        my $action = shift->{ $name };
        local $_ = $_[0];
        return &$action;
    }
}
sub new {
    my $self = bless {}, shift;
    my $current_name;
    @_ = %{ shift() } if &_HASH( $_[0] );
    while ( local $_ = shift @_ ) {
        given ( $_ ) {
            when ( !_IDENTIFIER( $_ )) {
                croak( "Invalid parameter name: $_!" );
            }
            when ( 'event' )   {
                croak( "Invalid event name: $_!" )
                    unless $current_name = _IDENTIFIER( shift )
                    ;
                _make_handler( $current_name );
            }
            when ( 'action' ) {
                croak( 'Action not code reference!' )
                    unless my $action = _CODE( shift )
                    ;
                croak( 'No active handler name!' ) unless $current_name;
                $self->{ $current_name } = $action;
            }
            default {
                croak( "Invalid event: $_!" )
                    unless $self->{ $_ } = _CODE( shift )
                    ;
                 _make_handler( $_ );
           }
        }
    }
    Carp::croak( 'Nothing handled!' ) unless %$self;
    foreach ( grep { !_CODE( $self->{$_} ) } keys %$self ) {
        Carp::croak( "Handler for $_ is not complete!" );
    }
    return $self;
}
```